# SQL order by custom result set column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to group multiple union selects with an order-by statement. (Not `GROUP BY` group, but a visual grouping)

Consider this:

```
SELECT 'First Query' QRY, Field1, Field2
    FROM Tabl1
    WHERE Field1 <= 5
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Second Query', Field1, Field2
    FROM Tabl1
    WHERE Field1 >5 
ORDER BY QRY, Field1;
```

I'm getting `ORA-00904: "QRY": invalid identifier` when I try to run such a query on an oracle database. Is something wrong with my syntax? Do I need to qualify the column identifier with each UNION ALL? If I don't include the ORDER BY, the query runs fine and the result set headers are proper, too.

Or does this just not work?

Thanks for any help, sorry for asking such a trivial question but you would not believe how hard this stuff is to google. Or I'm just bad at it.

Comment: First off, the question is not trivial (PROOF: you already got two incorrect answers to it.) Now: the query EXACTLY as written should do exactly what you expected it to do: you don't need to add aliases in the second branch of UNION ALL (if you add them, they will be *ignored* anyway), and ORDER BY at the end of UNION ALL is applied to the RESULT of UNION ALL, even if you don't "use parentheses" (you don't put the UNION ALL in a subquery). It is very likely that your ACTUAL query does NOT look like what you posted here.

Comment: I just did some testing. I see a problem (it looks like a bug to me) - if you have **three** branches to UNION ALL, and give the alias only in the first branch and add ORDER BY at the very end, you get the error you saw. No idea why that is. If you add the alias to the *second* branch (but still not to the third), the query works correctly. And, even with the aliases only on the first branch, `ORDER BY 1` does work. (Although it is always best to use actual column names, not column numbers.)

Comment: @mathguy This is what I had assumed. I have had a few UNIONS Stringed together with only the first column fully qualified. Strange behavior.

Comment: @mathguy This could be worth another question as to why this behavior is.  I confirmed it too.  With two queries union all'd together, and aliases only on the first query, the alias works in the order by.  But adding the third query without aliases, it breaks.  I have a preference though, and that is to alias each query.  During debugging or such, it is helpful to pull each query out on its own so it having its own aliases can be helpful, both to run it and to understand it.

Comment: @TheGrandDuke - I just posted something about this on OTN, and getting ready to read the replies :-)   https://community.oracle.com/thread/4025246  Better to see input from both web sites; there are many excellent contributors who only visit one of the two (SO and OTN).

Comment: Well then, I actually feel like I found something useful! :D

Comment: @Wep0n - certainly. I had posted something about the "order of operations" with UNION ALL (not wrapped in a subquery) and GROUP BY and ORDER BY on OTN just recently (as expected, GROUP BY applies to each branch, but ORDER BY applies only to the entire result set of UNION ALL), but I hadn't run into this bug. Good to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to just use a subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM ((SELECT 'First Query' as QRY, Field1, Field2
       FROM Tabl1
       WHERE Field1 <= 5
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT 'Second Query', Field1, Field2
       FROM Tabl1
       WHERE Field1 > 5 
      )
     ) t
ORDER BY QRY, Field1;
```

In a `union all` the fields come from the first query.

Of course, this is entirely unnecessary, because you can do all this in one query:

```
select (case when field1 <= 5 then 'First Query' else 'Second Query' end) as qry,
        field1, field2
where field1 is not null
order by qry, field1;
```

Actually, the `order by qry` is unnecessary too.  It is redundant because the value is based on `field1`:

```
select (case when field1 <= 5 then 'First Query' else 'Second Query' end) as qry,
        field1, field2
where field1 is not null
order by field1;
```

Comment: I am... You know. Thanks.

Comment: This is **incorrect**. If ORDER BY appears at the end of UNION ALL, then the ordering applies to the **RESULT** of the union, not to the second branch of the UNION ALL. You will see that clearly if you write a small query with a UNION ALL and an ORDER BY at the end, and you look at the Explain Plan - the ordering is done at the very end.

Comment: He's right on this though: For my purpose here, having union alls is not necessary. I have rewritten my query, it's about 5x more performant and only an eighth of the length. :)

Comment: @Wep0n - that is OK, for your purposes. However, for everybody else, your question was about the "order of evaluation" between ORDER BY and UNION ALL (when no "parentheses", i.e. subqueries, are used), and Gordon gave the wrong answer. He corrected that now.